# unable to access html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm stumling upon a weird problem: The code just wont be able to access the canvas element. Consider this code:

```
this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
this.context2D = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Firefox would produce an error say `this.canvas is null`. But if I write it like this:

```
this.canvas = $('#canvas');
this.context2D = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Firefox would tell `getContext is not a method`. I looked into `this.canvas` and see an unfamiliar object (no idea where it comes from but it definitely not a canvas).

And this is not exclusive to Firefox, Chrome produce the same result. I'm getting crazy over this.

---

edit: the entire html is here

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <title>Background test</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/soundmanager2.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/base.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Resources.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Actor.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Commons.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Graphics.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Utils.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
            new Commons().startupCommons();
            new Graphics().startupGraphics();
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css"> 
        body { font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}
        canvas {border-style:solid; border-width:5px; border-color:green;}
    </style> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <canvas id="visualcanvas" width="800" height="600"> 
        <p> 
            Your browser does not support the canvas element.
        </p> 
    </canvas> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I just added window.onload, but the problem persist. `this` in the before code refer to the Graphics object, which is call when `window.onload` fire.

Comment: dont know where can I upload code?

Comment: You can paste it into the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is $? Is it Prototype.js? I'm going to assume it is jQuery.

If you call `jQuery(someselector)` then you will get a jQuery object. If there are no elements that match the selector, then it will be a jQuery object with no items in it.

Either way, you can't treat it as a canvas object.

The first set of code doesn't work, probably, because there is no element with the id 'canvas' in the DOM at the time the line of JS is executed. This is most likely because you are running the JS in a script element that appears before the element with the id 'canvas' (and haven't done anything to delay execution, such as calling it via the document ready event) or because you are confusing the id attribute and the tag name.

Comment: The first part is definitely true. The second part is probably true.

Comment: I have the canvas element inside the html. In fact, it work perfectly before. But after I made some changes to the javascript, it start to behave strangely, I didn't change the html, the element is still there.

Comment: The element has the id 'visualcanvas' you are looking for an element with the id 'canvas'. As I said in the question "you are confusing the id attribute and the tag name" (or you are showing us code which doesn't match what you are actually writing)

Comment: okay, that solves the problems. I tried changing the id to fix this that I did'nt remember just now. Probably the problem at first was to try to call these functions without using window.onload. I own you a load!